# auto images replacement using ajax or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

i want this to be done:

There are 3 images in the folder. "img1.jpg", "img2.gif" and "img3.jpg"

As soon as anyone clicks on "img1.jpg", "img2.gif" will replace it. The gif file will run for 3 Sec and after that "img3.jpg" will replace the gif file automatically. After clicking "img3.jpg", it will be able to redirect to another site ex. www.google.com. Please note that replacement of image should be done without loading the page (AJAX) and images must have identical width and height so that everything will look smooth.

Note: The mouse pointer must always change to "hand" (Same as when we hover mouse to any anchor text)

Comment: I don't see a problem but rather a request. SO is for solving coding problems.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need PHP for this. This is a simple **example**:

**HTML**:

```
<img src="img1.jpg"/>
```

**CSS**:

```
img { cursor: pointer; }
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        $img.attr('src', 'img2.gif');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $img.attr('src', 'img3.jpg')
                .wrap('<a href="//www.google.com"></a>');
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

I hope this helps. If it is not appropriate to answer downvoted questions, tell me.